# Mac redirect LAN request to localhost

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip-address

I have program X on my mac which makes a request to 10.96.232.120:30323 through UDP.

I want to redirect this request to localhost somehow so that program X is really doing a request to localhost:8000.

How can I do this?

It's also possible I can put program X onto a virtual machine in virtualbox and redirect the request
that way, but I haven't been able to set that up either.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. You do

`sudo ifconfig en0 alias 10.96.232.120`

as shown in: https://osxdaily.com/2009/08/05/how-to-create-an-ip-alias-in-mac-os-x-using-ifconfig/